# How to map to a json using an array in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to make my array into a JSON format, in the form off it will say Skill Score: then the score for each of the elements in the array.

Tried using the .map function and then console logging as JSON.stringify as shown below.

```
if(Capability == 'CCM'){
            var newArray = this.finalSkills.map(function(item) {
                return {'Skill Score' : item}
            })
            console.log(JSON.stringify(newArray))
        }
```

Expecting something such as:
{
SKill Score: 3
}
{
Skill Score: 2
}

At the moment it is giving me ƒ stringify() { [native code] } in my browser console.

Comment: Think I figured it, just removed the JSON.stringify part

Answer (score 0):

> Expecting something such as: { SKill Score: 3 } { Skill Score: 2 }

This is not a string format for an array. A proper JSON format for an array would be `[{'Skill Score': 2}, {'Skill score': 3}]`
You can achieve what you want by using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
{...newArray}
```

```js
const newArray = [{'Skill Score': 3}, {'Skill Score': 5}];
const jsonFormat  = {};
Object.assign(jsonFormat, ...newArray)

console.log(...newArray)
```